# Coefficient of $x^n$ in the series

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

How will we find the coefficient of $x^n$ in the following series:
$$(1+x+2x^2+3x^3+...)^n$$

Please suggest if there is some formula or if it can be computed using the computer in $\log n$ time. I have figured out the differentiation approach which is slow.
Thanks in advance.I am guessing matrix multiplication/exponentiation and linear algebra could help.
Edit: I tried multinomial theorem too, but couldn't build on the solution as it requires the coefficients to be constant.

Comment: try multinomial theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: Is this an infinite sum raised to $n$ ?

Comment: I have to find the coefficient of x^n, the terms after nx^n wont really matter as they wont contribute in the coefficient.The infinite sum actually makes the expression simpler if one follows the multinomial approach. That is the reason i put that over here

Comment: the infinite sum will be undefined if $|x|\geq 1$

Comment: as we are only concerned about the coefficient, we can safely assume that to be less that 1 i.e. |x|<1 :)

Comment: Actually, we shouldn't be assuming anything about $x$, but rather we should treat it as a mere symbol in a formal power series.

Comment: $\binom{3n-1}{n}$ doesn't even work for $n=1$: it gives $2$ whereas $(1+x+\ldots)^1$ clearly has an $x$-coefficient of $1$.

Comment: Thinking about this as an algorithm, I wonder in what context this arises.  In other words, do we have any other information about the problem, like how big or how small $n$ can be?  You may be able to use lookup tables if $n$ is small.  Also, if we know where this problem comes from, we may be able to find other information that may help to solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly, for every $\lvert x\rvert<1$:
\begin{align}
1+x+2x^2+3x^3+\cdots&=1+x\frac{d}{dx}\big(1+x+x^2+\cdots\big)=
1+x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\\
&=1+\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
f(x) &=(1+x+2x^2+3x^3+\cdots)^n=\left(1+\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\right)^n \\ &=
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{2k}}
=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} \,x^k\Big(\sum_{j=0}^\infty s_{k,j}x^j \Big),
\end{align}
where $\sum_{j=0}^\infty s_{k,j}x^j=(1-x)^{-2k}$.
The coefficient of $x^n$ is equal to 
$$
c_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}s_{k,n-k},
$$
where $s_{k,n-k}$ is the coefficient of $x^{n-k}$ of $(1-x)^{-2k}$. But
$$
s_{k,n-k}=
\left.\frac{1}{(n-k)!}\frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}}\right|_{x=0}\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2k}}\right)
=\frac{1}{(n-k)!}\cdot\frac{(k+n-1)!}{(2k-1)!}=\binom{k+n-1}{n-k},
$$
and thus
$$
c_n
=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k-1}{n-k}.
$$

Comment: it is a solution of another problem

Comment: $
1+x+2x+3x^2+\cdots=\frac{d}{dx}\big(1+x+x^2+\cdots\big)
$ is not correct, rather it will be $$
1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\cdots=\frac{d}{dx}\big(1+x+x^2+\cdots\big)
$$

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu: See corrected version

Comment: @Leox: True. I fixed it.

Comment: To compute this is O(n) would you know of a faster version?

Comment: @user103260, Sage can't simplify that sum, so it's not Zeilberger-summable, and since it's a hypergeometric summand that means you're not going to find a hypergeometric closed form.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=1+x+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+\dots\\
xf(x)&=\hphantom{1+\,}x+\hphantom{2}x^2+2x^3+3x^4+\dots\\
(1-x)f(x)&=1\hphantom{+x\,\:}+\hphantom{2}x^2+\hphantom{2}x^3+\hphantom{3}x^4+\dots\\
&=1\hphantom{+x\,\:}+\frac{x^2}{1-x}\\
f(x)&=1+\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\\
f(x)^n&=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{m=k}^\infty\binom{n}{k}x^k\binom{-2k}{m-k}(-x)^{m-k}
\end{align}
$$
The coefficient of $x^n$ is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{-2k}{n-k}(-1)^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k-1}{n-k}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:(Assuming $|x|<1$)

$(1+x+2x^2+3x^3+.....)^n$

$=((1+x+x^2+....)+(x^2+x^3+x^4+....)+(x^3+x^4+x^5+.....)+......))^n$

$=(\frac{1}{x-1}+x^2.\frac{1}{x-1}+x^3.\frac{1}{x-1}+....)^n$

$=(\frac{1}{x-1})^n(1+x^2+x^3+....)^n$

$=(\frac{1}{x-1})^n(1+\frac{x^2}{x-1})^n$

Comment: Interesting fiddling there mate, i am trying to work out a solution, though +1 for your attempt, i think this may help

Comment: going by what you have written above, wont the original expression be equal to 1/(1-x)^2n? In that case the coefficient of x^n in 1/(1-x)^2n will be (2n+n-1)C(n) which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
1+x+2x^2+\cdots+x^n+\cdots=1+x(1+2x+n x^{n-1}+\cdots)=1+\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.
$$
Then 
$$
(1+x+2x^2+\cdots+x^n+\cdots)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}\frac{x^i}{(1-x)^{2i}}.
$$
Now you need to calculate 
$$
[x^n]\frac{x^i}{(1-x)^{2i}}, i \leq n,
$$
it is doable.